# Bytes Object is Comma Separated Decimal Values (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, integer, byte, endianness

A machine I interface with at my work returns its frequency as a bytes object like this:

```
b'192,232,206,0'
```

This little-endian (I think that's right, I'm not great at remembering which is which) bytes object is supposed to translate to a hex bytes object \x00\xCE\xE8\xC0 which translates into decimal as 13560000. I have found that Python has `int.from_bytes()` which takes the hex bytes object and turns it to a nice integer, but when I apply that to my comma-separated bytes object where each bytes is a decimal value, I get an astronomically large number (3816634650710199623094969186609 to be exact). Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit convoluted but you can convert the decimal numbers to hex strings and combine their byte values to assemble a number:

```py
freq = b'192,232,206,0'
freq_bytes = b''

for decimal in freq.split(b','):
    hex_str = hex(int(decimal))
    if hex_str == '0x0':
        hex_str += '0' # otherwise it won't convert
    freq_bytes += bytes.fromhex(hex_str[2:]) # remove the 0x part

freq_int = int.from_bytes(freq_bytes, 'little')
```

gives `13560000`